# Bootstrap columns not responsive for dropdown user profile

Tags: bootstrap-4

I have a user profile dropdown menu. I have created a row and columns for user picture/initials, name and title. Here is my code.

```
<div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2">
                    <% if UserProfile.exists?(user_id: current_user.id) %>
                    <% if current_user.user_profile&.photo %>
                      <img class="avatar-circle user-profile" id='base64image' src="<%= current_user.user_profile.photo %>">
                    <% else %>
                      <div class="avatar-circle user-profile">
                        <span class="initials user-profile-initials"><%= current_user.initials %></span>
                      </div>
                    <% end %>
                  <% end %>
                </div>
              <div class="col-xs-* col-sm-* col-md-*">
                 
              <% if UserProfile.exists?(user_id: current_user.id) %>
                <%= UserProfile.find_by(user_id: current_user.id).first_name %> <%= UserProfile.find_by(user_id: current_user.id).last_name %>
                </br>
                <small><%= UserProfile.find_by(user_id: current_user.id).title %></small>
              <% else %>
                <%= current_user.email %>
              <% end %>
              
              </div>
             
             
              </div>
```

The issue is it looks proper on desktop but seems to stack up on mobile view. Any ideas how to tackle this?
Images:
[Desktop view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Uv9R.png)

[Mobile view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Hbuw.png)

Comment: `<div class="col-xs-* col-sm-* col-md-*">`  is incorrect.  The `*` needs to be replaced with values, typically between 1 and 12, representing the width of the section in terms of  bootstrap `col`s for xs, sm, and md (and larger) devices respectively.

Comment: Can you post a plain HTML version? It'll be easier for us to replicate.